# Play framework - java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: java, playframework, securesocial

I am new to play framework and trying to run securesocial as in https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial
Using Play 2.3, Scala 2.10.0

.sbt file is configured as

```
name := "SecureSocial-parent"

version := Common.version

scalaVersion := Common.scalaVersion

lazy val core =  project.in( file("module-code") ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val scalaDemo = project.in( file("samples/scala/demo") ).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(core)

lazy val javaDemo = project.in( file("samples/java/demo") ).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(core)

lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).aggregate(core, scalaDemo, javaDemo) .settings(
     aggregate in update := false
   )
```

But getting below error

```
~\securesocial-master>activator run
[info] Loading project definition from ~\securesocial-master\project
[info] Set current project to SecureSocial-parent (in build file:~/securesocial-master/)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last securesocial-master/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (securesocial-master/compile:run) No main class detected.
```

The project compiled successfully with many warnings on deprecated API
Any pointer will be useful on how to resolve the no main class error

Comment: isn't secure social just a library?  are you trying to run the sample?

Comment: @ChrisDaMour: Yes trying to run sample/java/demo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand it, SecureSocial-parent is just the library - it can be compiled, but cannot be *run* per se. You can only run the demo projects. For example, if you start `activator` in the `securesocial` directory, you can type

```
project javaDemo
```

to switch to the Java demo project and then

```
~run
```

to run it.

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same problem. I am using the scala version though. I am running the sample app directly from the samples/scala/demo folder (by typing activator in the terminal).

The key to get it up and running was to add the following line to scalaDemo.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

which should probably be

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

into the javaDemo.sbt file, since you are running the Java version.

I can see when the app starts that I have problems loading some gifs in the public folder, so maybe it is a wrong approach.